# Standardizing time columns in r

Tags: r, time, time-series, frequency, sampling

I have 14 columns in a list that represent continuous timed trial where data was sampled at different times.

my data looks like this:

|  | time1 | time2 | time 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 10 | 15 |
| 2 | 4 | 11 | 16 |
| 3 | 5 | 12 | 17 |
| 4 | 6 |  | 18 |
| 5 | 7 |  |  |

how do I Standardize all 14 columns so the first row starts at zero and the last row has the  samples duration end time for each column . The freq =0.004 and each sample duration varies(~.5 seconds).

So each row of data changes .004. Lets say the first row begins at 2.000 and the next is 2.004 so on and the end of the column is 2.504. So I need to change the first row to 0 and last row to .504. For all 14 columns in the list.

Comment: Could you clarify what your desired output would look like?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean about the frequency and the varying sample duration. My guess is you want to turn `time2` from `10, 11, 12` to maybe `0, 1, 2` or `seq(0, 2, length.out = 5)` or `seq(0, length.out = 3, by = 0.004` or something like that, but I have no idea which one.

Comment: its frames per second. 1/f.  So each row of data changes .004. Lets say the first row begins at 2.000 and the next is 2.004 and the end of the column is 2.504.  So I need to change the first row to 0 and last row to .504.  the exact same for the other columns.